# Timed out after 30 seconds waiting for presence of element located by

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

My below code was working fine but now, I am getting timed out response. I am not sure how to handle this timed out issue - kindly advise.

```
public void Browse_Samsung() throws Exception 
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        act.moveToElement(Digital_Menu).perform();
        act.click(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='CategoryMenu1']//a[@title='Samsung']")))).build().perform();

        WebElement Micromax = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='filter_1Option_21']//a[@title='GSM Mobile Phones - Micromax']")));

        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);arguments[0].click()", Micromax);

    }
}
```

Scenario:

1. Login to www.homeshop18.com
2. Choose "Samsung" from the "Digital" Menu
3. Now from the "Brand" section displayed on the left
   side, I need to SCROLL and select another brand named "Micromax".

> Error:
>   org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 30 seconds waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath: //*[@id='filter_1Option_21']//a[@title='GSM Mobile Phones - Micromax']

Comment: Check if all the locators are still valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, It Is Perfectly working for me.I am able to click on "Micromax"

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);

action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Digital"))).build().perform();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Samsung")));

driver.findElement(By.linkText("Samsung")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='input inputBox_filter_Brand']")).sendKeys("Micromax");

WebDriverWait wait1= new WebDriverWait(driver,30);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@title='GSM Mobile Phones - Micromax']")));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='GSM Mobile Phones - Micromax']")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong id at your xpath:

```
//*[@id='filter_1Option_21']//a[@title='GSM Mobile Phones - Micromax']
```

You should use **filter_1Option_20** but better use xpath:

```
//li/a[@title='GSM Mobile Phones - Micromax']
```

I think your filter IDs are not constants so its better to don't use IDs in your xpaths.